# Behaviour of ObjectContext using AutoFac and MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, autofac

I am using AutoFac as a IoC to inject the ObjectContext inside the Controllers that needs it.

The ObjectContext is registered in AutoFac using `InstancePerLifetimeScope`, and I have created a custom Controller factory that resolves the correct controller from the DI-container, and thereby gets the ObjectContext injected.

When I request a page, everything looks fine, and the data is fetched from the database using EF4 as expected.

The behavious I am wondering about is that after I have started up the web application, and I go to delete or add some entries from the database manually, those changes are not reflected inside my web app. I had 10 records in the database, deleted 5, but still all 10 records are fetched by EF. I thought that when I registered the ObjectContext in AutoFac with `InstancePerLifetimeScope` that meant a new ObjectContext got created per web request.

Now it seems that the same ObjectContext is used at all times, if I have not misunderstood something about how EF caches.

In addition to not seeing the changes I make to the database from other applications, I guess this will cause problems in production when all users that connect to the site uses the same ObjectContext, since the ObjectContext is not threadsafe.

Anyone knows where I went wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that your custom `IControllerFactory` is at fault. If you're using the latest Autofac/MVC integration, use `AutofacDependencyResolver` rather than a controller factory.

If using an older Autofac/MVC, use the provided controller factory and make sure the `ContainerDisposalModule` described on the Autofac wiki is correctly set up in `Web.config`.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure it like this

```
builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().As<IDataContext>().AsSelf()
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, in AutoFac you can use lifetime scopes as an alternative to the missing **Web Request Context** lifestyle: create a new lifetime scope at the beginning of each web request and use it to resolve components. Then **dispose of the scope when the request ends**.

So my guess is that you should not dispose your scope at the end of the request ?